# Vertical scrollbar not working after using component adapter. How to solve?

Tags: swing

I was writing a standalone prescription writing software using java, the program is almost usable but I am not satisfied with certain things. I have used layers of panels arranged mainly on gridBagLayout, and observed that when I resize my window to a lower size, horizontal scrollbar appears, although things could be managed only with vertical scrollbar if we could resize the contents in a different manner. To overcome this I have used component adapter. This resizes the contents successfully but vertical scrollbar becomes non functional. To demonstrate this problem I have created a small test program. Probably, if we can solve this, the solution can be implemented in the larger original one. Thank you in advance for your valuable time and effort.

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    
    static JFrame f=new JFrame("The Test");
    static GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    static GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel(gridbag);
    static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    static JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    static JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea("");
    static JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea("");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;      
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(panel1, c);
        panel.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(new JLabel("To check the resize behavior..."));

        String s = "This is such a beautiful day... ";
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        ta1.setText(s);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(ta1);
        JScrollPane scrPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel2);
        scrPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(scrPane1, c);
        panel.add(scrPane1);
        
        s = "Lets enjoy our day... ";
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        ta2.setText(s);
        ta2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta2.setLineWrap(true);
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        panel3.add(ta2);
        JScrollPane scrPane2 = new JScrollPane(panel3);
        scrPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        c.gridx = 1;  
        gridbag.setConstraints(scrPane2, c);
        panel.add(scrPane2);
        
        f.add(panel);
        f.setSize(1000,500);  
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        f.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Dimension d = new Dimension((int)panel.getSize().getWidth()/2 -JScrollBar.WIDTH-20, (int)panel.getSize().getHeight());
                panel2.setPreferredSize(d);
                panel3.setPreferredSize(d);
                f.repaint();
            }
        });//*/
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You should NOT be using a ComponentAdapter. The proper layout manager will dynamically resize components. 2) It looks to me like you should be using a `GridLayout`. It will make the two components the same size.

Comment: I was using GridBagLayout. The reason I tried using ComponentAdapter is that when I resize window to a smaller size horizontal scrollbar appears and part of the panel becomes invisible.

Comment: Thanks for provoking thought. Here the `ScrollPaneLayout` does not display the panel in the way I wish it to do. Is there any way to tell `ScrollPaneLayout` how to display it's panel?

Comment: I'm not really understanding your problem. Maybe you want to limit the width of the panel in the scroll pane and have component grow/shrink as the frame size changes? If so then you can check out the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) and use the "FIT" parameter. Then just use an appropriate layout manage you the panel that allows the components to dynamically resize.

Comment: You understood perfectly. It solves the problem. One new caveat: In my original program I have added `JTextField` within the Scrollable Panel and typing text in these fields opens up autocomplete windows. When I try to select option by pressing up or down key, the Scrollable Panel also moves.

Comment: Ok. I solved that too using `consume()` inside `KeyPressed()` function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @camickr I solved the problem using `ScrollablePanel` which is available [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/).

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    
    static JFrame f=new JFrame("The Test");
    static GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    static GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel(gridbag);
    static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    static ScrollablePanel panel2 = new ScrollablePanel();
    static ScrollablePanel panel3 = new ScrollablePanel();
    static JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea("");
    static JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea("");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;      
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(panel1, c);
        panel.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(new JLabel("To check the resize behavior..."));

        String s = "This is such a beautiful day... ";
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        ta1.setText(s);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        panel2.setScrollableWidth(ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT);
        //panel2.setScrollableBlockIncrement(ScrollablePanel.VERTICAL, ScrollablePanel.IncrementType.PERCENT, 110);
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(ta1);
        JScrollPane scrPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel2);
        scrPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(scrPane1, c);
        panel.add(scrPane1);
        
        s = "Lets enjoy our day... ";
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        s = s + s + s + s + s + s + s + s;
        ta2.setText(s);
        ta2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta2.setLineWrap(true);
        panel3.setScrollableWidth(ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT);
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        panel3.add(ta2);
        JScrollPane scrPane2 = new JScrollPane(panel3);
        scrPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        c.gridx = 1;  
        gridbag.setConstraints(scrPane2, c);
        panel.add(scrPane2);
        
        f.add(panel);
        f.setSize(1000,500);  
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should explain the solution in this answer - comments might have led to it but are fragile :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).